# How to clear QML Menu correctly

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a dynamicaly created Menu. The code below is just to understand the hierarchy

```
Menu {
    id: mainMenu
    MenuItem {
       text: "item"
    }
    Menu {
       title: "submenu"
       MenuItem {
           text: "submenuitem"
        }
    }   
}
```

Now I need to remove all mainMenu's content. As I can see in the documentation, Menu have methods `removeItem`, `takeItem` and `takeMenu`. Using `takeMenu` and `count` property I can access menu's children and remove them recursively. But what if I don't know the order and type of menu items? `Item` has not property `count`. I need some universal solution that can remove the item itself, and if it is a menu then remove all it's children.

Comment: Did you take a look at the Instantiator in Menu to dynamically create your menu ? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menu.html#items-prop

Comment: Yes, I did. The menu is created using custom Instantiator. So I don't clearly understand how to delete its children from qml, not from c++

Comment: The short example of the doc shows how it works. It's a model that you populate, so you just need to clear your model and your instantiator can handle it `onObjectRemoved: recentFilesMenu.removeItem(object)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's the cleanest solution, but it works well to clear your example.

```
while(mainMenu.items.length > 0)
    mainMenu.removeItem(mainMenu.items[0]);
```

You don't need to go recursively because when you remove an *Item*, all its [*childItems*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#children-prop) are removed with it.

Comment: Yes, this works well. Could you show me in docs where it's written that childitems are removed when parent removes? The problem is after calling your function we can still access to childItems of submenus by their ids...

Comment: Menu in QtQuick 2.0 doesn't have `items` property. But if we call `mainMenu.removeItem(0)` it works!